# SlimDX Lost Device: Try Catch performance?

Tags: c#, performance, try-catch, direct3d, slimdx

I'm using SlimDX and Direct3D9 classes to create a C# game engine.

I started with it one year ago and I remember that I successfully and safely managed to catch lost devices and reset them (on Windows 7). Now (on Windows 8) I started working on it again, but it looks like I'm not catching lost devices in any case anymore, especially in Ctrl+Alt+Del cases.

This is the previously working code: 
The "IsDeviceLost" method erroneously returns false at Ctrl+Alt+Del, so the device is about to present, but it crashes to a Direct3D9Exception: "D3DERR_DEVICELOST":

```
    public void Update(float time)
    {
        if (!IsDeviceLost(true))
        {
            _device.Present();
        }
    }

    private bool IsDeviceLost(bool resetIfNeeded)
    {
        bool deviceLost = false;

        // Check if DeviceLost is detected
        Result result = _device.TestCooperativeLevel();
        if (result == ResultCode.DeviceLost)
        {
            Log.Write(LogType.Warning, "Direct3D9Manager: Device lost and cannot be reset yet.");
            // Device has been lost and cannot be reset yet
            deviceLost = true;
        }
        else if (result == ResultCode.DeviceNotReset)
        {
            Log.Write(LogType.Information, "Direct3D9Manager: ResultCode.DeviceNotReset");
            // Device is available again but has not yet been reset
            if (resetIfNeeded)
            {
                // Reset device and check if it can work again
                _device.Reset(_presentParams);
                deviceLost = IsDeviceLost(false);
                if (deviceLost)
                {
                    // Reset failed, device still lost
                }
                else
                {
                    // Reset successful, device restored
                    // TODO: Reload textures and render states which are lost after a reset
                }
            }
            else
            {
                deviceLost = true;
            }
        }

        return deviceLost;
    }
```

So I researched the web about this problem and found several code, which puts the Update code into the try part of a try-catch block, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to fix this.

- Isn't try-catch slow for an Update method in a game engine which gets called every frame?
- Aren't there better ways to catch a lost device, which are not using try-catch?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to fret about perf when you lost the device.  You are not rendering anymore, the user couldn't care less.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes thats true, but with my current implementation thoughts, I would have to wrap up the content in the Update() method in a try catch block - update is called every frame and then left, so I enter a try catch block, leave it, enter it in the next frame again and so on. Isn't that slow?